No org.keycloak.cluster.ManagedCacheManagerProvider found
I am trying to run Keycloak in embedded mode within my Spring Boot app.
I am facing this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: No org.keycloak.cluster.ManagedCacheManagerProvider found. If running in embedded mode set the [embedded] property to this provider.

However, I have made sure to add this property to the META-INF/keycloak-server.json file:
  "embedded": "org.keycloak.cluster.ManagedCacheManagerProvider",

I am running on Java 21, Spring boot 3.2.4, Keycloak 22.0.0
This is the pom structure regarding keycloak:
<dependencies>
    <!-- Other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-dependencies-server-all</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-crypto-default</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-ui</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-rest-admin-ui-ext</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


I have this KeycloakApplication extension class:
public final class EmbeddedKeycloakApplication extends KeycloakApplication {

  @Setter
  private static KeycloakServerProperties keycloakServerProperties;

  @Override
  protected void loadConfig() {
    JsonConfigProviderFactory factory = new RegularJsonConfigProviderFactory();
    Optional<Config.ConfigProvider> optional = factory.create();
    Config.init(optional.orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No value present")));
  }

  @Override
  protected ExportImportManager bootstrap() {
    final ExportImportManager exportImportManager = super.bootstrap();
    createMasterRealmAdminUser();
    createRealm();
    return exportImportManager;
  }

  @KeycloakTransaction
  private void createMasterRealmAdminUser() {
    ApplianceBootstrap applianceBootstrap = new ApplianceBootstrap(KeycloakTransactionAspect.getSession());
    AdminUser admin = keycloakServerProperties.getAdminUser();
    applianceBootstrap.createMasterRealmUser(admin.username(), admin.password());
  }

  @KeycloakTransaction
  @SneakyThrows
  private void createRealm() {
    RealmManager manager = new RealmManager(KeycloakTransactionAspect.getSession());
    Resource lessonRealmImportFile = new ClassPathResource(keycloakServerProperties.getRealmImportFile());
    manager.importRealm(JsonSerialization.readValue(lessonRealmImportFile.getInputStream(), RealmRepresentation.class));
  }


I have made sure that the optional in loadConfig method has a value (it reads the keycloak-server.json file)
Overall, I see no other problems regarding my setup except for this.
Any help is appreciated.
